# Use MetadataType with Property Grid control?

Tags: c#, attributes, metadata

I have some auto generated classes and need to use the MetadataType attribute to apply various data annotations to the classes. This works great in my MVC app, now I need to use the same classes in a WinForms app and need to use the property grid control to display / modify object properties. It appears the property grid does not observe MetadataType, is there a simple way to get the property grid to see my data annotations?

Comment: I don't think you're gonna get anything good from winforms. If it is an option for you, you can create your own property grid in WPF with 50 lines of XAML and some 70 lines of C#, which supports any kind of custom properties and editors you define.

Comment: @HighCore That sounds interesting, I think I'll look into doing that. I'll post my solution for whatever I come up with.